# How to add value of a specific row, if value is in accordance in another df, using r?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I'm at a loss here. Loops are my weak spot.

I have two data frames and I'd like to add values conditionally to one of them.

This is how they look like:
df `links`

```
 OID_  FROM_X  FROM_Y  NEAR_X  NEAR_Y 
0    0 2679218 1237147 2679968 1237580
1    0 2679218 1237147 2678468 1237580
2    0 2679218 1237147 2679218 1238013
3    0 2679218 1237147 2679968 1238446
4    0 2679218 1237147 2680718 1237147
5    0 2679218 1237147 2678468 1238446
```

and df `centroid`

```
  FID_   GRID_ID       x       y  ID 
1    0   DD-122  2679218 1237147  1
2    1   DF-122  2680718 1237147  2
3    2   DG-122  2681468 1236714  3
4    3   DH-122  2682218 1237147  4
5    4   DI-122  2682968 1236714  5
6    5   DJ-122  2683718 1237147  6
```

So the idea is to add the `ID` of the `centroid`df to the `links`df. Therefore, the following condition needs to be fulfilled for a row in `links`:
`links$FROM_X == centroid$x & links$FROM_Y == centroid$y`

I'd be really happy if someone can help me with this. I really don't know how to start a loop like this.

Here is some data to try:
`links`

```
structure(list(OID_ = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0"), FROM_X = c(2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 
2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 
2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 
2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 
2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 
2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 
2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 
2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 
2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 
2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 
2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 
2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 
2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 
2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 
2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 
2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 
2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 
2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 
2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 
2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 2679217.82115, 
2679217.82115, 2679217.82115), FROM_Y = c(1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 
1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 
1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 
1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 
1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 
1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 
1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 
1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 
1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 
1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 
1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 
1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 
1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 
1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 
1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 
1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 
1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 
1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 
1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 
1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 
1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1237146.74329), NEAR_X = c(2679967.8101, 
2678467.83218, 2679217.82115, 2679967.8101, 2680717.79909, 2678467.83218, 
2680717.79909, 2677717.84315, 2679217.82115, 2679967.8101, 2678467.83218, 
2680717.79909, 2681467.78814, 2681467.78814, 2677717.84315, 2681467.78814, 
2679217.82115, 2676967.85411, 2680717.79909, 2677717.84315, 2682217.77719, 
2681467.78814, 2679967.8101, 2678467.83218, 2676967.85411, 2682217.77719, 
2679217.82115, 2676217.86515, 2682217.77719, 2681467.78814, 2680717.79909, 
2682967.76615, 2677717.84315, 2676967.85411, 2682967.76615, 2679967.8101, 
2678467.83218, 2682967.76615, 2676217.86515, 2682217.77719, 2682967.76615, 
2679217.82115, 2683717.75511, 2681467.78814, 2676967.85411, 2680717.79909, 
2683717.75511, 2677717.84315, 2676217.86515, 2682217.77719, 2679967.8101, 
2675467.87619, 2678467.83218, 2683717.75511, 2682967.76615, 2679217.82115, 
2683717.75511, 2681467.78814, 2676967.85411, 2676217.86515, 2684467.74415, 
2682217.77719, 2680717.79909, 2677717.84315, 2682967.76615, 2684467.74415, 
2679967.8101, 2678467.83218, 2683717.75511, 2684467.74415, 2676217.86515, 
2682217.77719, 2679217.82115, 2681467.78814, 2675467.87619, 2676967.85411, 
2682967.76615, 2684467.74415, 2685217.73318, 2680717.79909, 2677717.84315, 
2683717.75511, 2685217.73318, 2679967.8101, 2678467.83218, 2684467.74415, 
2676217.86515, 2682217.77719, 2675467.87619, 2682967.76615, 2683717.75511, 
2674717.88714, 2681467.78814, 2676967.85411, 2679217.82115, 2680717.79909, 
2677717.84315, 2679967.8101, 2678467.83218, 2675467.87619), NEAR_Y = c(1237579.74961, 
1237579.74961, 1238012.756, 1238445.7623, 1237146.74329, 1238445.7623, 
1238012.756, 1238012.756, 1238878.7687, 1239311.775, 1239311.775, 
1238878.7687, 1237579.74961, 1236713.7369, 1238878.7687, 1238445.7623, 
1239744.78139, 1238445.7623, 1239744.78139, 1239744.78139, 1237146.74329, 
1239311.775, 1240177.78772, 1240177.78772, 1239311.775, 1238012.756, 
1240610.7941, 1238878.7687, 1238878.7687, 1240177.78772, 1240610.7941, 
1237579.74961, 1240610.7941, 1240177.78772, 1236713.7369, 1241043.80042, 
1241043.80042, 1238445.7623, 1239744.78139, 1239744.78139, 1239311.775, 
1241476.80678, 1237146.74329, 1241043.80042, 1241043.80042, 1241476.80678, 
1238012.756, 1241476.80678, 1240610.7941, 1240610.7941, 1241909.81311, 
1240177.78772, 1241909.81311, 1238878.7687, 1240177.78772, 1242342.81941, 
1239744.78139, 1241909.81311, 1241909.81311, 1241476.80678, 1237579.74961, 
1241476.80678, 1242342.81941, 1242342.81941, 1241043.80042, 1238445.7623, 
1242775.82579, 1242775.82579, 1240610.7941, 1239311.775, 1242342.81941, 
1242342.81941, 1243208.83209, 1242775.82579, 1241909.81311, 1242775.82579, 
1241909.81311, 1240177.78772, 1238012.756, 1243208.83209, 1243208.83209, 
1241476.80678, 1238878.7687, 1243641.8385, 1243641.8385, 1241043.80042, 
1243208.83209, 1243208.83209, 1242775.82579, 1242775.82579, 1242342.81941, 
1242342.81941, 1243641.8385, 1243641.8385, 1244074.84491, 1244074.84491, 
1244074.84491, 1244507.85121, 1244507.85121, 1243641.8385), Shape_Leng = c(866.012589959, 
866.01267656, 866.012700003, 1499.977904, 1499.9779, 1499.977954, 
1732.02531652, 1732.02540312, 1732.0254, 2291.25415704, 2291.25418977, 
2291.25417332, 2291.25413408, 2291.25415298, 2291.25423878, 2598.03799308, 
2598.0381, 2598.03816628, 2999.9559446, 2999.9559946, 2999.956, 
3122.45309222, 3122.45312293, 3122.45314695, 3122.45323633, 3122.45320197, 
3464.0508, 3464.05080623, 3464.05080624, 3774.86174659, 3774.86180482, 
3774.86184633, 3774.86184456, 3774.8618658, 3774.8618578, 3968.56868289, 
3968.56870179, 3968.56874268, 3968.56875598, 3968.56875599, 4330.0634828, 
4330.0635, 4499.93390001, 4499.9338986, 4499.9339986, 4582.5084413, 
4582.50838526, 4582.50847403, 4582.50847756, 4582.50847756, 4821.75458415, 
4821.75462439, 4821.75459971, 4821.75456558, 4821.75462439, 5196.0761, 
5196.07612276, 5267.74951671, 5267.74960213, 5267.74960642, 5267.74961078, 
5267.74960643, 5408.24745528, 5408.24748301, 5408.2475483, 5408.24757832, 
5678.82497899, 5678.82499219, 5678.82497084, 5678.82503411, 5999.9119026, 
5999.9119026, 6062.0888, 6062.08881847, 6062.08886628, 6062.08889269, 
6062.08886629, 6062.08888592, 6062.08891426, 6244.90626988, 6244.9062939, 
6244.90632584, 6244.90640395, 6538.25244291, 6538.25245438, 6538.25248417, 
6763.77532308, 6763.77532308, 6763.77537289, 6763.77537289, 6873.76257529, 
6873.76270622, 6873.76263106, 6873.76269653, 6928.1016, 7088.61943403, 
7088.61945519, 7399.2156926, 7399.21570273, 7499.8899432), ID = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA)), row.names = 0:99, class = "data.frame")
```

`centroids`

```
structure(list(FID_ = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
"19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", 
"30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", 
"41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", 
"52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", 
"63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", 
"74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", 
"85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", 
"96", "97", "98", "99"), GRID_ID = c("DD-122", "DF-122", "DG-122", 
"DH-122", "DI-122", "DJ-122", "DB-121", "DC-121", "DD-121", "DE-121", 
"DF-121", "DG-121", "DH-121", "DI-121", "DJ-121", "DK-121", "DL-121", 
"CZ-120", "DA-120", "DB-120", "DC-120", "DD-120", "DE-120", "DF-120", 
"DG-120", "DH-120", "DI-120", "DJ-120", "DK-120", "DL-120", "CZ-119", 
"DA-119", "DB-119", "DC-119", "DD-119", "DE-119", "DF-119", "DG-119", 
"DH-119", "DI-119", "DJ-119", "DK-119", "DN-119", "DP-119", "CY-118", 
"CZ-118", "DA-118", "DB-118", "DC-118", "DD-118", "DE-118", "DF-118", 
"DG-118", "DH-118", "DI-118", "DJ-118", "DK-118", "DN-118", "DO-118", 
"DP-118", "DQ-118", "DR-118", "DT-118", "CZ-117", "DA-117", "DB-117", 
"DC-117", "DD-117", "DE-117", "DF-117", "DG-117", "DH-117", "DI-117", 
"DJ-117", "DK-117", "DM-117", "DN-117", "DO-117", "DP-117", "DQ-117", 
"DR-117", "DS-117", "DT-117", "DV-117", "CX-116", "CY-116", "CZ-116", 
"DA-116", "DB-116", "DC-116", "DD-116", "DE-116", "DF-116", "DG-116", 
"DH-116", "DI-116", "DJ-116", "DM-116", "DN-116", "DO-116"), 
    x = c(2679217.82115, 2680717.79909, 2681467.78814, 2682217.77719, 
    2682967.76615, 2683717.75511, 2677717.84315, 2678467.83218, 
    2679217.82115, 2679967.8101, 2680717.79909, 2681467.78814, 
    2682217.77719, 2682967.76615, 2683717.75511, 2684467.74415, 
    2685217.73318, 2676217.86515, 2676967.85411, 2677717.84315, 
    2678467.83218, 2679217.82115, 2679967.8101, 2680717.79909, 
    2681467.78814, 2682217.77719, 2682967.76615, 2683717.75511, 
    2684467.74415, 2685217.73318, 2676217.86515, 2676967.85411, 
    2677717.84315, 2678467.83218, 2679217.82115, 2679967.8101, 
    2680717.79909, 2681467.78814, 2682217.77719, 2682967.76615, 
    2683717.75511, 2684467.74415, 2686717.7111, 2688217.68914, 
    2675467.87619, 2676217.86515, 2676967.85411, 2677717.84315, 
    2678467.83218, 2679217.82115, 2679967.8101, 2680717.79909, 
    2681467.78814, 2682217.77719, 2682967.76615, 2683717.75511, 
    2684467.74415, 2686717.7111, 2687467.70009, 2688217.68914, 
    2688967.67814, 2689717.66711, 2691217.64515, 2676217.86515, 
    2676967.85411, 2677717.84315, 2678467.83218, 2679217.82115, 
    2679967.8101, 2680717.79909, 2681467.78814, 2682217.77719, 
    2682967.76615, 2683717.75511, 2684467.74415, 2685967.72215, 
    2686717.7111, 2687467.70009, 2688217.68914, 2688967.67814, 
    2689717.66711, 2690467.65611, 2691217.64515, 2692717.62315, 
    2674717.88714, 2675467.87619, 2676217.86515, 2676967.85411, 
    2677717.84315, 2678467.83218, 2679217.82115, 2679967.8101, 
    2680717.79909, 2681467.78814, 2682217.77719, 2682967.76615, 
    2683717.75511, 2685967.72215, 2686717.7111, 2687467.70009
    ), y = c(1237146.74329, 1237146.74329, 1236713.7369, 1237146.74329, 
    1236713.7369, 1237146.74329, 1238012.756, 1237579.74961, 
    1238012.756, 1237579.74961, 1238012.756, 1237579.74961, 1238012.756, 
    1237579.74961, 1238012.756, 1237579.74961, 1238012.756, 1238878.7687, 
    1238445.7623, 1238878.7687, 1238445.7623, 1238878.7687, 1238445.7623, 
    1238878.7687, 1238445.7623, 1238878.7687, 1238445.7623, 1238878.7687, 
    1238445.7623, 1238878.7687, 1239744.78139, 1239311.775, 1239744.78139, 
    1239311.775, 1239744.78139, 1239311.775, 1239744.78139, 1239311.775, 
    1239744.78139, 1239311.775, 1239744.78139, 1239311.775, 1239744.78139, 
    1239744.78139, 1240177.78772, 1240610.7941, 1240177.78772, 
    1240610.7941, 1240177.78772, 1240610.7941, 1240177.78772, 
    1240610.7941, 1240177.78772, 1240610.7941, 1240177.78772, 
    1240610.7941, 1240177.78772, 1240610.7941, 1240177.78772, 
    1240610.7941, 1240177.78772, 1240610.7941, 1240610.7941, 
    1241476.80678, 1241043.80042, 1241476.80678, 1241043.80042, 
    1241476.80678, 1241043.80042, 1241476.80678, 1241043.80042, 
    1241476.80678, 1241043.80042, 1241476.80678, 1241043.80042, 
    1241043.80042, 1241476.80678, 1241043.80042, 1241476.80678, 
    1241043.80042, 1241476.80678, 1241043.80042, 1241476.80678, 
    1241476.80678, 1242342.81941, 1241909.81311, 1242342.81941, 
    1241909.81311, 1242342.81941, 1241909.81311, 1242342.81941, 
    1241909.81311, 1242342.81941, 1241909.81311, 1242342.81941, 
    1241909.81311, 1242342.81941, 1241909.81311, 1242342.81941, 
    1241909.81311), coord_coun = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), ID = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", 
    "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", 
    "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "32", "33", 
    "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", 
    "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", 
    "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", 
    "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", 
    "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", 
    "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", 
    "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "101", "102", "103"), ID1 = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", 
    "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", 
    "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "32", "33", 
    "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", 
    "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", 
    "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", 
    "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", 
    "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", 
    "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", 
    "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "101", "102", "103"), end22 = c("11", 
    "1", "0", "9", "4", "22", "0", "9", "7", "8", "0", "0", "21", 
    "120", "158", "16", "45", "53", "7", "3", "0", "9", "0", 
    "21", "0", "46", "182", "19", "120", "184", "39", "25", "2", 
    "3", "6", "7", "0", "25", "212", "57", "97", "205", "11", 
    "0", "0", "6", "0", "88", "8", "1", "4", "13", "56", "251", 
    "74", "110", "181", "213", "115", "41", "8", "0", "3", "3", 
    "16", "74", "55", "22", "9", "0", "168", "254", "225", "223", 
    "184", "68", "256", "94", "0", "0", "10", "10", "0", "5", 
    "4", "19", "0", "3", "87", "90", "88", "52", "27", "330", 
    "588", "121", "251", "128", "109", "98"), end44 = c("10", 
    "1", "0", "10", "4", "23", "0", "9", "7", "8", "0", "0", 
    "22", "120", "156", "16", "46", "54", "7", "3", "0", "9", 
    "0", "21", "0", "47", "184", "19", "121", "188", "40", "25", 
    "2", "3", "6", "7", "0", "26", "214", "58", "95", "208", 
    "12", "0", "0", "6", "0", "89", "8", "1", "4", "13", "57", 
    "254", "76", "109", "181", "215", "116", "42", "8", "0", 
    "3", "3", "16", "75", "56", "23", "9", "0", "170", "254", 
    "233", "226", "185", "70", "262", "96", "0", "0", "10", "10", 
    "0", "5", "4", "21", "0", "3", "87", "90", "91", "52", "27", 
    "332", "598", "119", "261", "129", "112", "100")), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but did you want to just "join" your two data frames?

You can indicate with columns you want to add to your `links` data frame from `centroids` (in this case, perhaps `x` and `y` to merge, and `ID`).

If this is not what you had in mind please let me know.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(links, centroids[,c("x", "y", "ID")], by = c("FROM_X" = "x", "FROM_Y" = "y"))
```

Or in base R:

```
merge(links, centroids[,c("x", "y", "ID")], by.x = c("FROM_X", "FROM_Y"), by.y = c("x", "y"))
```